# Looking for a good repository for academic drafts

Tags: publications, thesis

I'm currently submitting my CV for Ph.D positions and internships at research labs. I have one publication already, and I am currently in the process writing my Master's thesis. I would very much like to attach a hyperlink in my CV to directs to my thesis since it is more telling of the work I've been doing than say my publication. I'm wondering if there is exists a "version control" paper repository, similar to say the way [Github](https://github.com/) works for software developers? What I mean by this is a place where I can upload improvements to my thesis without necessary making it publicly available (it can only be accessed via the hyperlink). My reason for doing this is fairly obvious. I can actively make improvements to my thesis after I have submitted the relevant documents, which the committee members viewing my dossier would later see. Does anyone know of such a resource?

Comment: Files in your public dropbox folder fit your criteria.

Comment: @DavidKetcheson Thank you! I don't know why I didn't think of this.

Comment: I recommend _Zenodo_ or _figshare_, with a preference to the former. Check [my relevant answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/53983/12391) for details. Those solutions are better than Dropbox, Google Drive and similar solutions in many ways, including built-in version control, potential for social interaction, discoverability and DOI assignment, which makes your materials easily citable.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh Can you share by link only on Zenodo (see my comment to Jeon's answer)?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Sure. For example, I can share via [regular link](https://zenodo.org/record/13143) or via [autogenerated DOI link](http://dx.doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.13143), which redirects to the same resource. Disregard the name of this particular resource, which is messed up a bit, but so far I haven't had the time to spend on figuring out this issue with my GitHub release management.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh But that is a *public* document. It will be found by a [search](https://zenodo.org/search?ln=en&p=diss-floss-official&action_search=). If I read correctly, OP wants the document to be *private* and accessible to the world *only* via the link.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Both _Zenodo_ and _figshare_ offer restricted access (I haven't tried it, though) and/or private workspace. In addition, _figshare_ offers private link sharing. Either of options/features should solve the problem. By the way, I just discovered that _figshare_ also offers DOI assignment and, even, reservation, in addition to other nice features. Having said that, I still think that from a **long-term perspective**, _Zenodo_ is a better option, as it is a not-for-profit organization, funded by EU and uses extremely solid IT infrastructure of CERN.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh I tried out Zenodo and it's confusing to get what I want. How do I update my already uploaded document?

Comment: @user119264: I'm sorry to hear that. However, I won't be able to help you beyond my general advice (it's been a while since I used it and I have used public workspace then). You would have to figure it out - I doubt it's rocket science, though (plus, you can always ask specific questions here or other relevant SE sites, read documentation, check their forums, ... - you know the drill :-). Sorry I couldn't help you more.

Comment: @user119264: I decided to briefly refresh my memory on Zenodo's functionality. I submitted a primitive test document via main UI (not GitHub integration) and tried to update it. I don't see any versioning functionality for directly uploaded documents. Thus, it appears that the only way to achieve your goal (hosting of research documents with update and versioning functionality) in Zenodo is to use its **GitHub integration**. Unfortunately, I don't have time to play with it right now, but you should be able to easily try that and share your results with us. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with LaTex, use it with git.

Edit and mess around with paper on `master` branch, and push some good, meaningful and confirmed improvements on your work into `release` branch.

If you need a repository private until you decide to make it public, use [Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/) or [GitLab](https://gitlab.com/), instead of github. They provide free private repository. When you finished your paper, you can change repository settings to public.

I am not sure whether `Diff`-ing PDFs---your previous and current paper---is easy problem or not. But you can choose a solution among several: [pdfdiff](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/people/cas.cremers/misc/pdfdiff.html), [DiffPDF](http://www.qtrac.eu/diffpdf.html), [pdf-diff](https://github.com/JoshData/pdf-diff), [diff-pdf](https://vslavik.github.io/diff-pdf/) and etc.

Comment: You can set up your own git repo with controlled access using [gitosis](https://github.com/tv42/gitosis).

Comment: -1 because it looks like you misunderstood the question. OP knows about github, and they are looking for a way to make the thesis not public nor private, but reachable only via a link that they put on their CV.

Comment: All three provide hyperlink of raw files. Get a raw link of a single file, and shorten with goo.gl, bit.ly or something.

Comment: @vonbrand: I would say that self-hosted versions of the de-facto standard Git services are better solutions. I'm talking about _GitHub Enterprise_ (very expensive) or much more affordable (and even free for the most of GitHub functionality) _GitLab_.

Comment: @Jeon That won't help -- if a file is public, it can be found by other means, too (e.g. the github search box), and it will be indexed by Google.

Comment: I don't understand. Is there any considerable reason that public repo should not be indexed. One workaround is to separate LaTeX source repo (private) and PDF repo (public). Another workaround is use self-hosted git and block non-human bots from accessing public repo.

Comment: @Jeon OP doesn't want a public repo. OP wants a private repo to which they can give access to selected people by giving them a hyperlink.